# Dart error, This constructor should initialize field 'x' because its type 'int' doesn't allow null

Tags: dart, constructor

I'm new to Dart. This is my code:

```
class Point {
  int x;
  int y;

  Point(this.x, this.y);

  Point.same(int i) {
    x = i;
    y = i;
  }
}

main() {}
```

I got this error when running it.

```
bin/dart1.dart:7:3: Error: This constructor should initialize field 'x' because its type 'int' doesn't allow null.
  Point.same(int i) {
  ^
bin/dart1.dart:2:7: Context: 'x' is defined here.
  int x;
      ^
bin/dart1.dart:7:3: Error: This constructor should initialize field 'y' because its type 'int' doesn't allow null.
  Point.same(int i) {
  ^
bin/dart1.dart:3:7: Context: 'y' is defined here.
  int y;
      ^
```

As I understand, the parameter `int i` of `Point.same()` is non-nullable, and I use it to initialize `x` and `y` (`x = i; y = i;`). Why it still asks me to initialize `x` and `y`? I even tried the following code and still got the same error:

```
class Point {
  int x;
  int y;

  Point(this.x, this.y);

  Point.same() {
    x = 3;
    y = 3;
  }
}

main() {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When initializing fields from a constructor without constructor parameters, use the [initializer list](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list). It runs prior to the constructor body and allow you to initialize final and non-nullable variables without marking them late.

```dart
class Point {
  int x;
  int y;

  Point(this.x, this.y);

  Point.same(int i) :
    x = i,
    y = i;
}

main() {}
```